# Как посчитать количество слов в тексте Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый вечер! Есть такая простая задача:
Есть список слов, а потом вводится неограниченное кол-во строк со словами.
Нужно проверить, есть ли слово из списка в строках и вывести кол-во строк, где есть хоть одно это слово.

```
текст про яблоко и яблоки
текст про яблок
яблоко вкусное
на дереве яблоко
с яблоком
витамины в
```

Вывод:

```
6 # так как 6 строк, в которых хоть 1 раз упоминается слово с корнем **яблок**
```

Comment: Нет, этот код считает именно строки, в которых есть слово, а название переменной `word` просто дезинформация

Comment: @ CrazyElf изменил вопрос, извините

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно всего лишь добавить `break`, прервав внутренний цикл проверки после первого найденного вхождения слова в строке:

```
if var in line:
    count += 1
    break
```